# weak convergence and trace operator (Neumann boundary condition)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, boundary-value-problem, trace

We have $f_k \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(0,T;W^{1,2}(\Omega))$, where the $f_k$ are said to satisfy the boundary condition $\nabla f_k \cdot\text{n}|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ in the sense of traces. Further we have $\Delta f_k$ bounded in $L^p((0,T)\times \Omega)$ for some $p \geq 1$. Then it is claimed that $\nabla f \cdot \text{n}|_{\partial \Omega}=0$ in the sense of traces but I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. My idea is:

By the bound for $\Delta f_k$, it follows $\nabla f _k \rightharpoonup \nabla f$ in $L^2(0,T;W^{1,p}(\Omega))$. From the trace theorem we have $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ embedded in $L^q(\partial \Omega)$ and may thus conclude

\begin{equation}
\nabla f_k \rightharpoonup \nabla f \ \ \ \text{in } L^2(0,T;L^q(\partial \Omega)) \nonumber
\end{equation}

and thus

\begin{equation}
\nabla f_k \cdot \text{n} \rightharpoonup \nabla f \cdot \text{n} \ \ \ \text{in } L^2(0,T;L^q(\partial \Omega)). \nonumber
\end{equation}

Hence,

\begin{equation}
\|\nabla f \cdot \text{n}\|_{L^2(0,T;L^q(\partial \Omega))} \leq \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|\nabla f_k \cdot \text{n}\|_{L^2(0,T;L^q(\partial \Omega))} = 0,
\end{equation}

which gives us the claimed statement.

My question is now, if I may argue like this? In particular, I'm not sure if this is what sense of traces means in this case, because we only consider the boundary of $\Omega$ and have in addition the time interval $(0,T)$. In the way stated above, don't we need $\nabla f(t) \cdot \text{n}|_{\partial \Omega}=0$ for all $t \in (0,T)$?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the concrete definition of 'in the sense of traces'?

Comment: By the trace theorem there is a unique continuous and linear operator $S:W^{1,p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^q(\partial \Omega)$ for some $q$, $Su=u|_{\partial \Omega}$ for $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, so 'in the sense of traces' means that we consider $f_k = S(f_k)$ on $\partial \Omega$, since otherwise $f_k$ would not be uniquely defined on the boundary.

Comment: Then using this continuous operator, your argument looks correct to me.